# how to delete links to http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

In order to improve my page speed i have to eliminate this from my wordpress.

how to delete links to http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php

Also another facebook script is inserted in my code and i did not succed to find it:

```js
id="fb-root"></div><script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/(function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(d.getElementById(id))return;js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}(document,'script','facebook-jssdk'));/*]]>*/</script><div
id="page_wrapper">
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: in gt metrix i get this:

Serve resources from a consistent URL 
  
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 34.0KiB.

http://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=42
https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=42

Comment: Those URLs are called in the background by the social plugins – nothing you can take any direct influence on (apart from completely removing those plugins from your site.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem for the Facebook widget

you can disable Facebook snippet

[image]

I've had this issue on https://ostadkar.pro/blog/ and have fixed this issue